# How can i Implement "Login with Twitter" via OAuth.io?

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, twitter, oauth.io

Hello I'm trying to implement "login with twitter", but it wont work on live website.

I followed [this](http://%20https://coderwall.com/p/t46-ta/javascript-twitter-social-login-button-for-oauth) tutorial but it wont work on my implementation.

When I run it via MAMP the OAuth wont pop, but when I preview from  PHPSTORM it pop and the login will work.

I added a "console.log" to log the final OAuth response and nothing happens while running the website via MAMP (live server), only via PHPstorm.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //function stops doubleclicks

    $('#twitter-button-loggin').on('click', function() {
        console.log("clicked")

        const userLoginTwitter = {}
        // Initialize with your OAuth.io app public key
        OAuth.initialize('HwAr2OtSxRgEEnO2-JnYjsuA3tc');
        // Use popup for OAuth
        OAuth.popup('twitter').then(twitter => {
            // console.log('twitter:', twitter);
            userLoginTwitter.twitter = twitter
            // Prompts 'welcome' message with User's email on successful login
            // #me() is a convenient method to retrieve user data without requiring you
            // to know which OAuth provider url to call
            twitter.me().then(data => {
                userLoginTwitter.me = data
               // console.log('data:', data);
                //alert('Twitter says your email is:' + data.email + ".\nView browser 'Console Log' for more details");
            });
            // Retrieves user data from OAuth provider by using #get() and
            // OAuth provider url
            twitter.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true').then(data => {
               // console.log('self data:', data);
                userLoginTwitter.SelfData = data
            })

            console.log(userLoginTwitter)
        });

    })
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Vais Gostar </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/base.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/oauth-io/oauth-js/c5af4519/dist/oauth.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/anime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/base.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.12.0/bootstrap-social.min.css">

</head>
<body >
 

<a id="twitter-button-loggin" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Sign in with Twitter
</a>


<a id="twitter-button-loggin" class="btn btn-danger">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Log Out
</a>

</body>


</html>
```